# 404 on json file when deployed in a subdirectory to azure app service

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, blazor

When attempting to load a json file from a blazor Web App, hosted on Azure, json is returning as a 404 when there is a different root set up (ie. wwwroot/subdir).

When the output of the blazor web app is directly in the wwwroot, the json is returned fine with no 404.

I have tried amending the web.config with the relevant mime types, but to no avail.

The app is hosted in an App Service, deployed through Github Actions.

When the app is deployed into root, (wwwroot), the json files load fine. However, when I update the base in the index.html and  in the project file so that it lives under a subdir then the json isn't loaded, and instead returns a 404. Locally it all works fine.

The json exists in the directory, as I have ftp'ed on to it, I have changed the file type to .txt and it is there and downloads fine through the browser when navigating directly to it.

I've seen a lot of comments around similar issues with the web.config, but this is fine, with the:

```
<remove fileExtension=".json" />
```

and

```
<mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
```

Not sure what else to try.

UPDATE 1:

99% certain it's to do with the dislike of downloading json files.

The json files have a gz alternative, which i can navigate to and download directly (e.g. zzz.json.gz) but with the .gz (zzz.json) the files still return 404.

UPDATE 2:
When viewing the logs on the server, I can see an error of "SECURITY_DENIED_BY_MIMEMAP" which then throws up the 404.

The Mimetype is definitely set, so I'm not sure what else it could be.

Comment: What is your `<base href="???"`. Was it changed for publishing to a subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, it was changed to <base href="subdir" />

Comment: please go through the [link](https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/deploy-blazor-application-in-azure-app-service.aspx) it might help you